# Couldn't adb reverse: device 'adb' not found in expo react native visual studio

Tags: react-native, visual-studio, android-studio, adb

I am working on the expo react native in visual studio and when trying to open android emulator it shows the error:

Couldn't start project on Android: `Error running adb: device 'adb' not found`

PLEASE HELP ME REGARDING THIS.

Comment: Make sure Android SDK is installed and in your PATH. If you just have installed the necessary Android components close all programs and re-open them to make the updated PATH work. Or simply reboot your system.

Comment: Hi, i added java jdk in the environment variable and later it worked but now again giving the same error i dont know what actually goin on please help me regarding this i stuck in this probem from past few days./

Comment: I was talking about Android SDK, not JDK. What does the comand `where adb.exe` output?

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate it because i dont know command adb.exe. Please let me know about it.

Comment: There are "tags" below your question, just point your cursor on `adb` and you will be enlightened. Furthermore if you don't know something it might be a good ide to first query Google or your favorite search engine if it presents a simple answer to you.

Comment: I know about that but i dont know where to set this problem.

Comment: I posted a command you should execute on command-line (cmd.exe or powershell.exe). So what is your problem?

Comment: When i writing adb.exe in command prompt it is written 'adb.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: That means you don't have Android SDK installed or not in PATH.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I downloaded the sdk platform tools and put the path in environment variables. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote 2 days a go...